# WUSA not finding KB3114409

Tags: windows-7, hotfix

For context KB3114409 was that update for Microsoft Outlook which caused it to get stuck into safe mode. [Link](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3114409)

When I try to uninstall this update from machines using WUSA.exe and this command:

```
wusa /uninstall /kb:3114409 /quiet /norestart
```

I am told that the update could not be found on the computer. However, if I check it through the Control Panel I can see it and uninstall it that way.

I believe this is something to do with the fact we have a 32-bit installation of Microsoft Office on a 64-bit version of Windows which is why using WUSA fails.

Can anyone shed some light on this?

Comment: You need to indicate you want to remove the x86 update your current syntax is indeed assuming x64 which is indeed not installed

Comment: @Ramhound, how do I specify the x86 package?

Comment: I would assume adding [`-x86`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/934307) then the file extension of the actual [update](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3114560) file would do it.

Comment: @Ramhound. I'm not quite sure I understand you. I tried the switch /kb:3114409-x86.msu and it just gave me the usage information.

Answer (score 1):

WUSA is only used for Windows updates and patches, not Office. You can use MSIEXEC in the following fashion:

```
msiexec /i {90140000-0011-0000-0000-0000000FF1CE} MSIPATCHREMOVE={14CDCBF7-3CCC-42E2-A5BB-2D4926E16FAA} /qn
```

You should likely force close Outlook prior to uninstallation. But I haven't tried without closing.

Sources:

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/8a042082-f71d-4939-824b-ea1946ae95f9/wusa-uninstall-kb3114409-quiet-norestart?forum=outlook

http://blog.jocha.se/tech/uninstall-outlook-kb3114409

Comment: I'll test this tomorrow morning on a spare machine. I'll let you know what comes of it.

Comment: Well, what did come of it?